# getExtra() is giving a null value when referenced inside onClickListener

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle

I am not sure why I am getting a null for activation code below. Any pointers/explanation on how it works would be really helpful. Thanks

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
.
.
.

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    final String activationcode = bundle.getString("activationcode");
    etActivationCode = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_LoginForgotPasswordOk_Code);

    btnForgotPasswordOk = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_LoginForgotPasswordOk_OK);
    btnForgotPasswordOk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String inputActivationCode = etActivationCode.getText().toString();
            if( inputActivationCode == activationcode){ 
          //the value of activationcode above is null. Hence doesn't match ever
            }
        }
    });
```

However if I do something like the following, the value of activation code can be referenced

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            new CheckMatch().execute(activationcode);
           //the value of activationcode can now be accessed in the AsyncTask class CheckMatch
        }
```

Comment: are you sure is null? Or it is not matching because you are using `==` to compare strings?

Comment: Use equals to compare Strings

Comment: it should work same way both times

Answer (score 1):

You should ideally be using `equalsIgnoreCase()` for comparing two strings. If it still doesn't work, try converting your activationCode variable into a global variable (by declaring it outside onCreate, within the class). You can assign the value to this variable inside onCreate though (like how you are doing right now).

Answer (score 1):

`==` compares instances (pointers if you are familiar with C), not values. You should use `inputActivationCode.equals(activationcode)`.